# crash on UIPageViewController, trying to add new pages to Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to add a new page to the `page-based` project in xcode, the `DataViewController` takes the whole screen, so I could not add any button on the `RootVC`. So when I add a `IBAction` on the `DataVC`, there is a crash, I don't understand why, the exception just says

> thread 1, breakpoint 1.1

Here is the code :

```
//in DataVC, not sure if it is ok to create the DataVC inside itself
- (IBAction)addOne:(id)sender {
    DataViewController *dvc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataViewController"];
    [[ModelController sharedModelController] addOneToModel:dvc];
}

//in ModelController
-(void) addOneToModel:(DataViewController*)dvc{
    [self.pageData addObject:dvc];//ERROR HERE: not much details : "thread 1, breakpoint 1.1"
}

//the sharedMOdelController 
+(instancetype)sharedModelController{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static ModelController *sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[ModelController alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: How do you use pageViewController, how do you set viewControllers property to it, how do you use datasource, could you put some source code ? The code you have put does not have anything interesting.

Comment: Thanks @insane-36 for the support, it was the project that comes when you create a new page-based on xcode. I simply added the code above, but I had to use "mutableCopy" instead of "copy" , for a mutable array. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to do more detective work. Log your newly created DataViewController to make sure it isn't nil, and is the kind of object you think it is.

It is also possible that you have a breakpoint at that line and can't see it. The Xcode IDE and the debugger command line maintain separate lists of breakpoints, and I have seen a breakpoint disappear from the IDE but still show up in the debugger command line. Have you tried continuing?

You might also want to disable all breakpoints and see what happens.

You might also want to try adding an exception breakpoint for all Objective-C exceptions. Sometimes that provides more information when an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, you were right, when I continued I found out the problem was when I copy an array into a mutableArray, I should have used "mutableCopy" on the pageData variable created by the project by default. So, I would have another question if you don't mind: when I reach the page "december" (the project is the one that comes when you create a page-based project in xcode), even though I add new pages to the model, the pageViewController stops at december. Would you know why? The project uses "count" on pageData, to know the number of pages, and I added a new item inside pagedata...